# After Angular update npm install fails because of peer dependency conflicts

Tags: angular, npm

I'm having trouble updating my Angular version. When I use `ng update` I get the following output:

```
Name                                       Version                  Command to update
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cdk                               12.1.2 -> 12.2.0         ng update @angular/cdk
      @angular/cli                               12.1.2 -> 12.2.0         ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                              12.1.2 -> 12.2.0         ng update @angular/core
      @angular/material                          12.1.2 -> 12.2.0         ng update @angular/material
```

Afterwards I try to update all four of them using the command:

```
ng update @angular/cdk @angular/cli @angular/core @angular/material -C
```

The `package.json` is updated and afterwards `npm i` is run in order to install all packages. Here I encounter the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^12.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^12.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/localize@12.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/localize@"^12.0.0 || ^12.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^12.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I do not know why it says `Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.2` when in the `package.json` all @angular related files have `~12.2.0` declared as version.

Comment: What is in your package.json? This seem to say you need to update the two packages it says to the required version. It's not clear what exactly you don't understand here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try with deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then reinstall `npm` which might resolve your issue.

So, run the following commands:

```
remove node_modules 
remove package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: Solved it like this before you answered, but since you wrote the correct answer I guess you get the accepted answer

Comment: I wrote the correct answer and you gave him the credit - that's wrong

Comment: This work for me. But also I needed to update my npm version from https://nodejs.org/

Comment: I got this error after running `remove node_modules` remove : The term 'remove' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: @distance you could manually remove the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` or use `del` on Windows

Answer (score 18):

You should **never** upgrade Angular all the way across the board like that. Instead it's in hierarchical order - because many of those dependencies are just dependent upon one another. So several of them disappear.

It's very easy to fix this problem by just deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again.

This time though in order:

```
   npm install @angular/cli@latest -g
   ng update @angular/cli,
   ng update @angular/common
   npm install @angular/cdk@latest
   npm install @angular/material@latest
```

in angular 12.2 there are warnings about chokidar if you run **npm audit fix** it won't do anything, and there are several others - you just have to wait till they fix them because they're dev dependencies.

this is taken from a live project
current working version with universal:{

```
 "@angular/animations": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~12.1.0",
    "@easypost/api": "^3.11.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^12.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^8.8.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^14.1.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-image-resize-module": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
}
```

Comment: Despite fixing your commands to correct syntax it does not work this way for me because after `ng update @angular/cli` I already get a dependency error because of wrong @angular-devkit/build-angular version. Found 12.1.2, wants 12.2.0. 

I'm starting to believe that the project setup itself has problems. I didn't generate it myself but am only tasked with continuing work on it and wanted to update everything prior to starting.

Comment: sorry about that I didn't realize I had typed upgrade instead of update.  I put the current working versions for our deployed project with no mismatches from our package.json - hopefully that will help you...  you really need to delete the node_modules folder though, because those dependencies get stuck even sometimes upon update.

Comment: I already deleted the node_modules folder, in fact `ng update` does this by itself. The root of the problem seemed to be in the package-lock.json file. At least after deleting that file and then removing node_modules and running `npm i` it worked as expected. Maybe there were some peer dependencies described that caused the error.

Answer (score 8):

When getting peer dependency error run below command
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`
It will override all the dependencies in package.lock.json & package.json file of your project.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `node_modules` and install it again.
Also make sure`package.json` has no duplicated dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I use `npm install --force` and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For those who use yarn the solution is almost the same:

```
rm -r node-modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn install
```